# Merging Files in Tkinter Search Files Application

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am trying to build a simple application using Tkinter wherein I should be able to search files in my local folders and display them. For example, if I am searching a 'test.txt' file, it will return me that file plus all txt files. Now the second part of the problem is, I have to merge all the files that was returned to me in my search into one single file (I know it sounds absurd but please forgive me). I have successfully achieved the first part but not able to implement the second part. Quite new to functions and OOPs concepts. Pasting my code below in the hope for some guidance. Please forgive me for the code quality as I am quite new.

```
import pandas as pd

from tkinter import *

import os

from docx import Document

doc1 = Document()


def search_file():
    file_entry_name = entry.get()
    answer.delete(1.0,END)
    extension = file_entry_name.split('.')[1]
    file_name = file_entry_name.split('.')[0]
    file_entry_name = file_entry_name.lower()

    for r,d,f in os.walk('/Users/kausthab/Documents/Documents – Kausthab’s MacBook Air/DSBA'):
        for file in f:
            file.split()
            if file.startswith(file_entry_name) or file.endswith(extension):
                answer.insert(INSERT,file + '\n')

def merge_file():
    # files = os.listdir('/Users/kausthab/Documents/Documents – Kausthab’s MacBook Air/DSBA')
    # global answer
    # for i in answer:
    #     if i != '.DS_Store':  # i kept getting an error for a hidden file. So excluded it
    #         doc1.add_heading(i, 2)
    #         doc2 = Document(i)
    #         for para in doc2.paragraphs:
    #             para_in_doc = doc1.add_paragraph(para.text)
    #         doc1.add_page_break()
    # doc1.save('search.docx')
    return





root = Tk()

root.title('Docu Search')

topframe = Frame(root)
entry = Entry(topframe)
entry.pack()

button = Button(topframe, text="search",command =search_file)
button.pack()




topframe.pack(side = TOP)


bottomframe = Frame(root)


scroll = Scrollbar(bottomframe)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
answer = Text(bottomframe, width=80, height=50, yscrollcommand = scroll.set,wrap= WORD)
scroll.config(command=answer.yview)

merge_button = Button(bottomframe, text="merge",command =merge_file)
merge_button.pack()
answer.pack()



bottomframe.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: have You tried just using `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames` or any of the other `filedialog` methods? to import use `from tkinter import filedialog` or `from tkinter.filedialog import what_need` also don't do this: `from tkinter import *` it is bad practice and unless You really know what You are doing You should import only what You need for example `from tkinter import Button, Label, Frame, Tk` and so on or import module like this: `import tkinter` (You can also then use `import tkinter as tk` or any other name for example `import tkinter as kinter` or sth like that to make it shorter)

Comment: @Matiiss no I haven't. let me read through it first. thank you for the feedback!